# error document.getElementById(...).play is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here console is showing the error that document.getElementById(...).play is not a function

```
import React from 'react';
const musicComponent=(props)=>{
    const style={background:props.color}
    return(
        <div className="musicpad"   style={style} onClick={()=> 
            {document.getElementById("h"+props.index).onplay()}} >
        <audio className="sounds" id={"h"+props.index} 
            src={props.music1}  ></audio>
        </div>)
}

export default musicComponent;
```

Comment: `document.getElementById` returns an instance of the [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) class - I don't see anywhere in the documentation stating that is should have a method called `play` - what are you trying to do?

Comment: Firstly use of document.getElementById is wrong.Please don't use vanilla javascript to get DOM node. If you want to get reference use `ref` in react.

Comment: So I should add ref to my audio tag say myRef and then use myRef.play inside onClick function

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call `.onplay()`. Call `.play()` instead:

```js
function MusicComponent(props) {
  const audio = React.useRef()
  const playFromStart = () => {
    audio.current.currentTime = 0
    audio.current.play()
  }
  return (
    <div onClick={playFromStart}>
      <audio src={props.music1} ref={audio} />
      play
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<MusicComponent music1="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg" />,
  document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Can you please also tel how to set current time to 0 as now the play button works only after the particular music track is completed

Comment: @HarshvardhanSandhu To do that, set `.currentTime` to zero before calling `.play()` (I updated the answer so it does this)

Comment: @HarshvardhanSandhu If that worked please accept my answer 